# Generate web service java class from WSDL in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I would like to generate web service java class from WSDL in eclipse (Kepler version).

**Method used:**
1) Right click WSDL file
2) Select "Crete Web Service"
3) Select "Develop client" level ([as Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnzC7.png))
4) Finish

I able to generate `xxxProxy.java`, `xxxResponse.java` class. However, I failed to generate `xxxLocator.java` and `xxxSoapBindingStub.java` which are needed to call web service.

Appreciate for any advice on missing steps(if any)

Comment: not familiar with generating the service, but to generate the callers u can use SOAPUI generate code w/ axis

Comment: Hey Vincent if possible can you upgrade your eclipse to Oxygen? It will allow you to create Stub and Locator

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution for you might be upgrading your Eclipse Kepler Version to Neon or Oxygen, After that import your project into workspace and do following on wsdl file.

```
Right Click ***.wsdl --> Web Services --> Generate Client
```